# alignment of equations

Tags: equations, alignment

[image]

how can I display the equations like this? I tried \begin{aligned} but its all centered.flalign is showing errors as well

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What are you using now?  The information you've given isn't sufficient to give an accurate answer without guessing.  Please add a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows the problem you are now seeing.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    a &= b, a = b, a = b,\\
    a &= b, \\
    a &= b, a = b, \\
    a &= b, a = b, a = b,
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    a &= b,\\
    a &= b, a = b,\\
    a &= b, a = b, a = b \\
    a &= b, a = b.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This left aligns ALL the equations.  You can center them using `&&&` instead of `&` before aligned, but this looks more like the original.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  &\begin{aligned}
    a &= b, a = b, a = b,\\
    a &= b, \\
    a &= b, a = b, \\
    a &= b, a = b, a = b,
  \end{aligned}
\intertext{where}
  &\begin{aligned}
    a &= b,\\
    a &= b, a = b,\\
    a &= b, a = b, a = b, a=b \\
    a &= b, a = b.
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]